# What are the rules when setting the DisplayMember of the ComboBox in a WinForm program

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm learning WinForm, and in a recent practice, I wanted to realize such a function:
A ComboBox with some other controls in form. And ComboBox's DisplayMember is the "Name" of each control, and the ValueMember is their "Handle".
Like this.
[image: Application Picture]

However, it didn't work so well, and when I debug, I found the after binding the DataSource, the DisplayMember shows a empty string.
[image: Debug]

Also the ValueMember setting shows error if I set it "Handle".

Are there any rules when using these two properties?

Code are as follow.

```
cmbAllControls.DataSource = allControlsList;//DataSource, List<Control>.
cmbAllControls.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbAllControls.ValueMember = "TabIndex";//TabIndex is OK, but Handle will throw error.
```

Comment: Controls' Properties are returned in very different manners. A Control's Text, for example, is returned using `GetWindowText()`. Try to use the "Text" property as the `DisplayMember`. You might be surprised. You could (should) use a simple custom class, with some Properties (i.e., Name (string), Handle (IntPtr) and Control (Control). Use a `List<class>` as the `ComboBox.DataSource`. You can then access all the properties of any Control casting `SelectedItem` to your custom class Type.

Comment: Btw, I suggested the `Text` property becase that property is browsable. Also, possibly, set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before you set the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to the Browseable(false attribute) on [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handle?view=netframework-4.7.2).  When I try the code below it works fine if I remove the attribute but crashes with ArgumentException "Cannot bind to the new value member."

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DataSource = new List<MyObj>()
    {
        new MyObj(){Name = "Fish",MyInt = 3,MyIntPtr = new IntPtr(5),MyIntPtr2 = new IntPtr(7)}
    };

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "MyIntPtr";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "MyIntPtr2";
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("Selected:" + comboBox1.SelectedValue); };
}

private class MyObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public IntPtr MyIntPtr { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)] //This attribute causes the error
    public IntPtr MyIntPtr2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tried it once more, and it seems truly the Browable Attribute. The property with Browsable(false) can not be set as ValueMember(error) or DisplayMember(empty). Thank you so much.